# Symfony2 fixing array to string error

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a twig extension function created that count the total prices of items:

```
public function getTotal($items)
    {
    $total = array();
    foreach($items as $item){
        $total[] = $item->getPrice() - $item->getDiscount() + $item->getValue();
    }
    return $total;
    }
```

However when I display them i get **error: array to string conversion**

I am displaying like this:

```
{{getTotalTax(product)}}
```

I tried doing this which didnt help:

```
public function getTotal($items)
    {
    $totals = array();
    foreach($items as $item){
        $totals[] = $item->getPrice() - $item->getDiscount() + $item->getValue();

         if(is_array($totals)) {
        return '';
        }
    }
    return $totals;
    }
```

Comment: You return an array `$totals` which you're trying later to print. Maybe instead of using an array you can do something like: `$total += ...`

Comment: Hello. What I want is to display the total price of each product individualy thats why I need an array. If I do += it just prints the sum of all products

Comment: Why don't you add a method in your Product entity like "getTotalPrice()", which would sum up the discount of the item and the value?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is returning an array.

I assume you want to either:

- return each total in an array: *price* - *discount* + *value* for each item.
  In this case you need to fix your display function to get each total out of the array and print it out. e.g.

.

```
function print_totals($totals){
    foreach ($totals as $total){
       echo $total;
    } 
}
```

it's hard to say exactly what you're trying to do from your question, as you have your 'display' calling `getTotalTax(product)` where product seems to be a single item, but the function you pasted is called `getTotal()` which assumes an array of `$items`.

You might want to update a property on each item like so:

```
public function getTotal($items)
{
    $total = array();
    foreach($items as $item){
        $item->total = $item->getPrice() - $item->getDiscount() + $item->getValue();
    }
    return true;
}
```

**OR**

- return the grand total
  In this case you will need to keep adding to the total, like so:

.

```
public function getTotal($items)
{    
    $total = 0;
    foreach($items as $item){
        $total += $item->getPrice() - $item->getDiscount() + $item->getValue();

    }
    return $total;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are indeed returning an array and it cannot be converted to string. Depending what exactly you want you can return for example

```
return print_r($totals, true);
```

Otherwise you can extract individual elements from your HTML template and output these.

Comment: Can you explain more about the HTML template part?

Comment: getToalTax gives you array. No you get needed values from this array like for example {{ getTotalTax(product)["price"] }}